# mysql session variable as transaction id for audit

Tags: mysql

let's say all my transactions are like this

```
START transaction;
SET @transaction_id = UUID();
...other statements
COMMIT;
```

And I use the variable `@transaction_id` to identify the transaction in audit triggers. Is it safe to do that? Is it possible that a trigger in one transaction get the value of `@transaction_id` from a different transaction (let's assume I never forget updating the `@transaction_id` in a transaction)?

Comment: Why not use transaction id assigned already assigned by MySQL? `SELECT TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID())`

Comment: @symcbean Do you know how to do it for ndb? It seems to be the column `transid` of table `ndbinfo.cluster_transactions`. Not sure how to get the current one.

Comment: Sorry never used NDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, session variables are private to each connection. So, if you set a session variable like `@transaction_id` in a transaction, it won't be seen by other transactions from different connections.

However, if you have multiple transactions within the same connection, they can see the session variable. But since you're setting `@transaction_id` at the start of each transaction, this shouldn't be an issue.

So, yes, it's safe to use `@transaction_id` to identify transactions in audit triggers. Just make sure to always set this variable at the start of each transaction.

But remember, this method relies on your application correctly setting the `@transaction_id` variable. If it fails to do so, or if an error occurs before it's set, your audit triggers might not work as expected.

Also, if your application uses connection pooling (where the same connection is used for different user sessions), you might need to reset `@transaction_id` at the end of each transaction, or find another way to generate unique transaction IDs.

### Update based on comment

Correct, multiple transactions within the same connection will not be executed concurrently. They will be executed sequentially, one after the other.

As for connection pooling, if you always set `@transaction_id` at the start of each transaction, you shouldn't need to reset it at the end of each transaction. The new value you set at the start of the next transaction will simply overwrite the old value. However, it's good practice to reset or clear session variables when you're done with them, to avoid any potential confusion or issues. But in your case, as long as you're diligent about setting `@transaction_id` at the start of each transaction, you should be fine.

Comment: So multiple transactions within the same connection won't be executed concurrently right? And If I use connection pooling, do i still need to reset `@transaction_id` at the end of each transaction if I never forget setting @transaction_id at the start of each transaction?